Terminal launching but empty on Ubuntu 24.04
In terminal i see only blinking cursor, it does not respond to my actions. Terminal in other apps (IDE, VS code, 3rd party terminals) act in a same manner. Even virtual terminal ctrl + alt + F3 not responding, so i cant execute any command.

My issue kinda related to this one, but i can't execute fix (no terminal) and language settings also not helping.
I actually already reinstalled my OS (because of same issue) and terminal worked. But now am encountering it again. Just installed some popular programs (IDE, text editor e.t.c) and feels like am done nothing special or custom to fresh OS.

Have you opened your shell's initialization file(s) (e.g. ~/.bashrc) in a text editor and compared them with the defaults (e.g. /etc/skel/.bashrc)?

The diff is:
# Load Angular CLI autocompletion. \n source <(ng completion script)
And its the reason. I did not thought that angular installation might be related somehow to this terminal problem.
@steeldriver thanks!

Rollback to defaults in /etc/skel/.bashrc resolved issue.

Please add some details. How to roll back the default. Remember someone reading this may not have that experience.
